# Issues with text not refreshing randomly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I recently added a roll dice button but since I've added this I have noticed that my text does not show randomly after being refreshed over and over again and it only is selected randomly the first time you roll it and it will not refresh until you completely reset the whole page again.

I have tried to change everything back to where it was including the roll dice button but somewhere in the code, I believe I have gone wrong and that is why the text is not refreshing randomly anymore even though the videos are playing randomly after refreshing over and over.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" title="Default Styles"/>
    <script>

var r_text = new Array();
r_text[0] = "All leave are brown";
r_text[1] = "fafwfaf";
r_text[2] = "fakfjwkfkajwkfawjf";
r_text[3] = "cornflakes";
r_text[4] = "bannana";
r_text[5] = "Choclate";
r_text[6] = "lol";
var i = Math.floor(6*Math.random())

var videos = [{
    id: 1,
    url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/ngUMyF9D9SQ?autoplay=1",
    text: r_text[i]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/r-l_gVPVylM?autoplay=1",
    text: r_text[i]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/6ukTzRjXcR0?autoplay=1",
    text: r_text[i]
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/n5BXMNCTu8I?autoplay=1",
    text: r_text[i]
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/JtwVmnMNaEY?autoplay=1",
    text: r_text[i]
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/lAMgRaHP8Q4?autoplay=1",
    text: r_text[i]
  }

];

window.onload = function() {
  function rollVideo(numberRand) {
    let playerDiv = document.getElementById("random_player");
    if (document.querySelector("iframe") !== null) {
      document.querySelector("iframe").remove();
    }
    let player = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    let randomVideoUrl = videos[numberRand].url;
    player.setAttribute("width", "640");
    player.setAttribute("height", "390");
    player.setAttribute("src", randomVideoUrl);
    playerDiv.appendChild(player);
    document.getElementById("r_text").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("r_text").innerHTML = videos[numberRand].text;
  }


  document.getElementById("btn-roll").addEventListener("click", startRoll);

  function startRoll() {
    let currentNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);
    rollVideo(currentNumber);
  }
};





    </script>
</head>


<div id="random_player">
  <div id="r_text">
  </div>
</div>
<button id="btn-roll">Roll</button>
</html>
```

Comment: you can solve it this way: `document.getElementById("r_text").innerHTML = r_text[ Math.floor(6*Math.random()) ]`

Comment: Where should i add that?

Comment: replace this `document.getElementById("r_text").innerHTML = videos[numberRand].text;`

Comment: @GrafiCode And that would generate another random number different from the number supplied to the function.

Comment: document.getElementById("r_text").innerHTML = videos[numberRand].text; Instead of this should i put document.getElementById("r_text").innerHTML = r_text[ Math.floor(6*Math.random()) ]

Comment: @VermaJr. Per O.P.'s code `text: r_text[i]` every element in the object has the same text. So random for random...

Comment: Can you demonstrate it with the whole code?

Comment: @TauheedAhmad Do you want add the text randomly?

Comment: @VermaJr. Yes please since i want every video to be random which it is and not playing the same one as before as well as the text

Comment: @TauheedAhmad after you edited, your code is the same in my comment

Comment: What comment are you talking about?

Comment: @TauheedAhmad first comment

Comment: This is very confusing since your first comment im not sure which of the code i have you are relating it to that is why i asked for the whole code.

Comment: @TauheedAhmad Refer to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you have initialized `i` to a random number between `0` and `5` from the beginning and the `videos` object contains the same value for `text` for every index, viz. `r_text[i]`.

So, if you want to print random text for random videos, simply replace this

```
document.getElementById("r_text").innerHTML = videos[numberRand].text;
```

with this

```
document.getElementById("r_text").innerHTML = r_text[Math.floor(6*Math.random())];
```

or if the particular texts are fixed with the indices, then, simply put `text: r_text[0]`, `text: r_text[1]`,... and so on in `videos` object.

Comment: If we use ```document.getElementById("r_text").innerHTML = r_text[Math.floor(6*Math.random())]``` then this will create new random value which is not equal to ```numberRand``` so the mapping of text and video will be mismatch. We can use ```document.getElementById("r_text").innerHTML = r_text[numberRand];``` instead of creating new random value.

Comment: @MohitPrakash That is what he wants, a random text for a random video. No need to match it with `numberRand`.

Comment: finally, a clean explaination

Answer (score 0):

The error is 
text: r_text[i]
A solution is can be changing i for the the constante index videos.